# What is object in python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I am learning python and I came across with package in python. I made a directory containing `__init__.py` and `shipping.py`. In `shipping.py` the code is

```
def calc_shipping():
    print("calculating shipping cost")
```

I made another python file called `app.py` outside this directory to import this package

```
from package import shipping
#package.shipping.calc_shipping()
shipping.calc_shipping()
```

I want to know that when we called `shipping.calc_shipping()` it prints the message.The shipping in this is an object ? if it is then we should have class, we didn't declare any classes in our package. Somebody please clarify me with this concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python everything is an object. classes, functions, methods, even modules, operators and etc. (except for language tokens and keywords which make statements like `if-statement` , `try-except`... )

Every class in Python inherits from a base *object* class.

Functions are not exceptions, They are from type `function`:

```py
def fn():
    pass

print(type(fn))
```

output:

```
<class 'function'>
```

You don't need to define it in your module. `def` keyword will create an instance of this class for you.

It is available through `types` module:

```py
from types import FunctionType

def fn():
    pass

t = type(fn)
print(t is FunctionType)  # True
```

Comment: Meh, `__add__` isn't really the operator itself. I don't have a nice/perfect way of saying it, either, btw. I thought of "every value is an object", but that just moves the problem, as I'd then have to define what a "value" is.

Comment: @KellyBundy what about saying every *expression* is an object? expressions are anything that can be evaluated. Anything that can be passed to `eval` ? maybe

Comment: hi @SorousHBakhtiary that meas when we declare function/method in python we are actually creating object,we don't have to specify its class name its already there so when we use `def` in function it is creating object or it is inherting feature from base class. Am i right?

Comment: @aniketpant Yes when you define a function with `def` keyword you are creating an object which is the instance of type `function`. Let me tell you something, There is a special relationship between class `type` and class `object` that can't be reproduce in pure Python, So I think I'm going to confuse you because you are new sorry for that. But , both classes and instances of the classes are objects. They are also instances. Yes classes are instances themselves (of type `type`). All of the classes in Python(except `object` class itself) inherit from *object* class.

Comment: If say *expression* is the wrong level. The *result* of *evaluating* an expression is an object. Not the expression itself. Unless you mean it's a string object :-). But even if you say it as "result of ...", that again just moves the problem, then having to say what an expression is.

Comment: thank you @SorousHBakhtiary it will take time to me to understand the behaviour of class and object in python like as you said the relationship between **class type** and **class object**  and classes are instances themselves.